# Bidirectional brushless DC motor with high starting and holding torque on the cheap

Tags: camera

I'm working on a DIY camera gimbal project, and I came across the issue of finding adequate brushless DC motor that:

- Has enough starting and holding torque to lift and stably hold a 5kg mass when using a 60cm-length pulley
- Is fast enough to move that mass 1.25m/s
- Preferably costs under £25 ($32)

I've looked all over the internet on Amazon, Ebay, AliExpress, RS Components and more, but all I've found are things that have 5 times the specs I need, for 5 times the price, or things at £12 a piece but with half the specs. If there's some place I've missed, I'd really appreciate it if someone could help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Hw Recs! We usually give recommendations about electronic computing, so this may be off-topic for this site. This is probably why you couldn't find a tag to fit your question and put camera as your tag instead, which your question is definitely not about.

Comment: @BennettYeo Which site would you suggest I put it on instead? I used the tag 'Camera' because I need these for a camera project, so I thought it would be adequate.

Comment: Well the thing is, recommendation type questions are pretty specific to this site and software recs, so it may not fit anywhere else. We've defined Hardware as [any primarily electronic item that can perform more than one task, designed to interface with, connect to, or be, a primary computing platform in day-to-day operation](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware). I haven't voted your question for closure, so if the mods don't mark the question off-topic in the next few days you should be good.

Comment: You could try electronics.stackexchange.com, not sure how friendly they are to recommendations. Unfortunately, there's not a stackexchange for every question. area51.stackexchange.com is the place for new site proposals, if you're willing to put the time and effort into that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a hardware recommendation.